# Scrolling issues with SIP (keyboard) open on wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard, scroll

I am developing an application for WP7 platform (actually WP7.1 sdk). I have a page with an image and couple textboxes in a Grid encapsulated in scrollviwer, that supports both portrait and landscape orientation. I am facing some odd behaviors that rised my two questions:

1. Is there a solution or at least explanation why in Portrait mode when I focus on any textbox and SIP comes up I cannot scroll through the page in the rest of viewable area? When I try to scroll it with SIP up it always bounces back to the focused textbox so to select another textbox I have to tap elswere to hide the SIP and select another textbox. (its annoying and user unfriendly) In a landscape mode though, I can scroll through the page easily (without bouncing) and select whatever I want with SIP up. I think it has to do something with a fact that in portrait mode without sip you can see all elements and in landscape you have to scroll down to see some textboxes. But if I look into some system apps I see similar pages and it doesnt bounce to focused textbox with the keyboard up, so I dunno what am I doing wrong.
2. Is there any workaround to correctly position dropdown from autocompletebox control from toolkit while it is declared inside of scrollviewer? Its position is always messed up, most of the time I tried to solve this it showed up over the textbox itself hiding it.

Thanks for your time. 
I already did some research but didnt solve anything :-/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. I would recommend you to read Alex's [article on the subject](http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/). I think it should answer your problem just fine.
2. Not really. And you shouldn't have a `AutoCompleteBox` in a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: BringIntoView is not available in Silverlight

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alex's solution is acceptable I will try to implement it today.

Comment: Question is obsolete as well. The platform isn't eligible for development anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try my solution ? 
https://siphelper.codeplex.com/